# How to find the size of a remote ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I was installing the libv8 gem (which is ~512M) from rubygems and wondered why it was taking so long. This...

> gem specification -r libv8

... gave me nothing about the size of the gem. Then I looked in the [docs](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/), and it looks like the gem creator has the option of putting information about the size of their gem under one of rubygems's pre-defined "optional gemspec attributes".

Q: So one can't reliably know the size of a remote gem before one installs it?

Bonus question: Would it be impractical to make gem size a required gemspec attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a terrible way to do it on OS X or Linux:

```
curl -s  https://rubygems.org/api/v1/gems/<gem-name>.yaml | sed -n "s/gem_uri: //p" | xargs curl -sLI | grep -i Content-Length | tail -1
```

will give you the size (in bytes).

explanation:

use curl and the [rubygems api](http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-org-api/) to get some info about the gem:

```
curl -s  https://rubygems.org/api/v1/gems/thor.yaml
```

get the URL for the gem file download

```
sed -n "s/gem_uri: //p"
```

download the response header for the gem (following redirects)

```
xargs curl -sLI
```

show only the last instance of 'Content-Length', case insensitive

```
grep -i Content-Length | tail -1
```

result (~82k):

```
Content-Length: 83456
```

Comment: @Andreykul It should still work. Which step isn't working for you?

Comment: https://rubygems.org/api/v1/gems/<GEM_NAME> seems not to work

Comment: @dcts, you need to replace <GEM_NAME> with the name of the gem you want the size of and add ".yaml". See the example above with Thor: curl -s  https://rubygems.org/api/v1/gems/thor.yaml